# How can I style only certain columns in a div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a series of divs inside an overall container:

```
<div class="positionDivs">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <!--this goes on for a unspecified number of times-->
</div>
```

This displays as three columns inside the main div (positionDivs)

And what I need to do is style every third div in this container which I've done with:

```
.positionDivs div:nth-child(3n){
    background-color:black;
}
```

but I also (and this is the part I can't work out!) need to style the centre column. In the example above this would be numbers 2, 5 and 8.

Could anyone assist please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subtract one from what you have to select the previous div:

```
.positionDivs div:nth-child(3n-1){
    background-color:red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/axb8yesg/1/)**

Comment: You my friend are a genius!

Comment: @SxChoc Or he's just seen this question fifty times before :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `3n+2`

```
.positionDivs div:nth-child(3n+2){
   /* CSS Properties */
 }
```

or `3n-1`

```
.positionDivs div:nth-child(3n-1){
   /* CSS Properties */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `3n+2` in `nth-child`.

```
.positionDivs div:nth-child(3n+2){
    background-color:red;
}
```

OR `3n-1`, both return the same result.

```
.positionDivs div:nth-child(3n-1){
    background-color:red;
}
```